I don't understand what this woman said in radio station
I have some difficult to understand phonetic in English, i speak a bad English (but tourists can understand it), I can write (maybe with some errors) in English, but it's rare for me to understand what people said.
Someone understand the exact word spell by this female police station sound?

I think it is not intended to be intelligible.

I hear a police siren and a female dispatcher who is talking on an old speaker system that muffles the voices with a lot of static mixed in. Per @AntonSherwood, we don't need the content, only that there is some chaos as she communicates with police far away in their cars ... on equally bad speakers.

I’m voting to close this question because ELU is not a transcription service

Here’s the base for the clip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LzTD4MmWcX4 — slightly more decipherable (though it seems no one on the internets has definitively cracked the code).

What the woman is saying is not intended to be understandable, even to a native english speaker; it's just the kind of thing (chatter) you might hear in a police station. The woman is communicating over a police radio, or something like that, which gives her speech a specific, recognizable quality.
If the other sound effects weren't added on top of the woman talking, it might be possible to understand her.
I can't even hazard a confident guess, except I think in the middle she says "128" ("one twenty eight") and at the end she might be saying "C". So possibly she is saying some kind of police code.
Edit: I guess the source audio is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LzTD4MmWcX4, as someone points out, so judging from that it's probably "148" instead.

Yes, it's more police code numbers than English words.
